# CSS "white-space: nowrap" Not Working in Table Column

Tags: html, css

I have a table on a page that allows inline editing of items in a table. The last column in the table contains actions that can be performed on the item:

[image: actions]

However when the item is being edited and the input boxes are added the actions column begins to wrap. I have tried adding `white-space: nowrap` which had no effect. Is there another way to force the column not to wrap?

The rows are populated in JS based on [this template](http://pastebin.com/WTSSxH08).

Comment: Please show HTML and CSS code that reproduce the problem.

Comment: It won't work if you are floating your buttons, you will need `display: inline-block;` for that

Comment: Or post a JSfiddle pliz.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WTSSxH08 white-space: nowrap on the actions <td style="text-align: right;">. It's a template I populate in JS

Comment: Looks like you dont have enough width for the TD to accomodate three buttons. You can find out by giving `overflow:hidden` to the TD. IF that is the case you will have to adjust other row's content widths.

Comment: I have been struggling with IE10 recently and it seems to need the css rule `word-wrap: normal` to avoid wraping

Answer (score 0):

If you put `white-space: nowrap` it won't break!

```
.location-actions {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[See fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8rJr3/)